# Docker Delugevpn tracker timeout

Tags: 18.04, vpn, openvpn, docker, deluge

I have just finished setting up the binhex/delugevpn docker container and when using any torrent the tracker status shows "Error: connection timed out" after a couple of seconds.

I am new to docker so I may have done something wrong but from what I can tell everything looks to function except for the trackers timing out.

I have port forwarded the incoming ports for deluge in my router and am using PIA as my VPN.

```
            "VPN_PROV=pia",
            "STRICT_PORT_FORWARD=no",
            "NAME_SERVERS=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4",
            "DELUGE_DAEMON_LOG_LEVEL=info",
            "PUID=1000",
            "VPN_USER=xxxxxxxx",
            "DELUGE_WEB_LOG_LEVEL=info",
            "VPN_ENABLED=yes",
            "ENABLE_PRIVOXY=no",
            "DEBUG=false",
            "UMASK=000",
            "VPN_PASS=xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "LAN_NETWORK=192.168.1.0/24",
            "PGID=1000",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "HOME=/home/nobody",
            "TERM=xterm",
            "LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
```

Is anyone able to help? I am able to provide further information if required (I am just unsure what else would be useful)

EDIT - I have also attempted with the VPN disabled and the same issue still occurs

EDIT 2 - Doing ping tests also confirms the container is able to ping both host names and ip addresses

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, It involved stopping the container I had running with the issue and I created/run a new container with a slightly different config as follows.

```
 docker run
 --cap-add=NET_ADMIN
 -p 8112:8112
 -p 8118:8118
 -p 58846:58846
 -p 58946:58946
 --name=delugevpn1
 -v /home/docker/deluge/data:/data
 -v /home/docker/deluge/config:/config
 -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
 -e VPN_ENABLED=yes
 -e VPN_USER=xxxxx
 -e VPN_PASS=xxxxxxxx
 -e VPN_PROV=pia
 -e STRICT_PORT_FORWARD=no
 -e ENABLE_PRIVOXY=yes
 -e LAN_NETWORK=192.168.1.0/24
 -e NAME_SERVERS=209.222.18.222,37.235.1.174,1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8,209.222.18.218,37.235.1.177,1.0.0.1,8.8.4.4
 -e DELUGE_DAEMON_LOG_LEVEL=info
 -e DELUGE_WEB_LOG_LEVEL=info
 -e DEBUG=false
 -e UMASK=000
 -e PUID=0
 -e PGID=0
 binhex/arch-delugevpn
```

This now results in deluge being able to torrent/download again although I still have the tracker status still showing occasionally as "Error: Connection Timed out"